# Send data from Google Firebase Firestore to Salesforce

Tags: firebase, nosql, salesforce

I would like to know if it is possible to send data from my firestore firebase to Salesforce.
I have an ios application where i can create data and this data is stored in my Google firebase. Now i would like to send this data (in real time) to salesforce. If there is a change on a data, Salesforce should also be informed, that means that both of the database have to been synchronised.

Has anyone ever had to do this? If so, how do I go about it?

Comment: What about interacting with [Salesforce APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/integration-apis/) via Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution,

you can simply get the Http Json file response address of your firebase in Salesforce

```
 public static HttpResponse FirebaseToSaleforce(String myReqURL){
        //myReqURL='https://firestore.googleapis.com/your project fire base collection adress'
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(myReqURL);
        req.setMethod('GET');
        
        // Create a new http object to send the request object
        // // A response object is generated as a result of the request
        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);  
        return res;            
    }
```

the res will probably contain your data collection from firebase , just use it as you want, for example, create a specific object in salesforce